# Objective C Native Library Binding Issue in Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.ios-binding

We are trying to bind iOS native library with Xamarin, using the below link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/walkthrough?tabs=macos

But whenever we are trying to do so, we got a file where it contains lines more than 25k and errors more than 30-40k errors, And All these we get for a 3 lines of objective c code.

Comment: What are the "3 lines of objective c code"?

Comment: Hello @SushiHangover thanks for the reply , For testing purpose I've wrote this code.   +(void)Print
{
    NSLog(@"Objective C Native Library Binding");
}

Comment: I just bound a single static "Print" ObjC function and have an 11 line ObjcBindingApiDefinition file (`ApiDefinitions.cs`) (I removed the unused `using` statements).

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated Xcode and Objective Sharpie yet?
try to follow this tutorials: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lqSXKOH5g8&t=1618s

Another guide for you: http://blog.ksharp.info/2018/10/xamarin-native-binding-ios-cocoapods/

Comment: Yes I have updated Xcode and Sharpie as well. I followed the all instruction given in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/walkthrough?tabs=macos. But No success.

Comment: You can try the link above. I used to follow instruction from this link and I was success